# Help with writing a proof about $\liminf$ and $\limsup$

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove

$\liminf a_n+\liminf b_n≤\liminf(a_n+b_n)$

In trying to prove this thing, I’ve come up with the following proof:

$\limsup a_n+\limsup b_n \ge \limsup(a_n+b_n)$

$A+B \ge L - \epsilon$

Where $A= \limsup( {a_n: n>N})$, $B= \limsup {b_n: n>N})$, $L- \epsilon = \limsup ({a_n +b_n})$, and $S_N= \sup ({a_n +b_n: n>N})$

Now for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $M>0$
s.t. if $N>M$ then  $|\sup(a_n+b_n: n>N)-L|<\epsilon$ $\implies$ $S_N> L-\epsilon$ for every $N>M$ which means there exists $n>N$ s.t. $a_n+b_n>L-\epsilon$

I know this proof isn't the one I need but it has to be similar. I could use some help with proving $\liminf a_n+\liminf b_n≤\liminf(a_n+b_n)$.

Comment: ```$\limsup$ ```  ```$\liminf$ ```

Answer (score 2):

Since for all $m\geq n$,
$$\inf_{k\geq n} a_k+\inf_{k\geq n}b_k\leq a_m+b_m,$$
you get $$\inf_{k\geq n} a_k+\inf_{k\geq n}b_k\leq \inf_{k\geq n}(a_k+b_k).$$
Taking $n\to \infty $ gives the wished result.